# Setting up Spring Native Experimental (id 'org.springframework.experimental.aot' version '0.10.3' was not found in any of the following sources)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-native

Hello ladies and gentlemen,

so i was just trying to get a executable for my Spring application by using Spring Native.

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.experimental.aot' version '0.10.3'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.4'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.4'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.14'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.14.6'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and my settings.gradle:
`rootProject.name = 'demo'`

after adding the 'org.springframework.experimental.aot' version '0.10.3' plugin to the build.gradle as seen above (doing whats told in the documentary under 2.1.2 https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started), i get following error:

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.experimental.aot', version: '0.10.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.experimental.aot:org.springframework.experimental.aot.gradle.plugin:0.10.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Comment: When following a tutorial, do follow the tutorial and don't skip steps. You forgot https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_maven_repository (adding the repository).

Answer (score 13):

The person who commented is right, though I think unnecessarily rude given that the tutorial is out of order, and they tell you to apply the plugin prior to giving you instructions how to install.

More specifically, you need to add the spring release maven repo to your `settings.gradle.kts` in order to source the plugin

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/release") }
    mavenLocal()
  }
}
```

and then also add the repository to your `build.gradle.kts` in order to source the dependencies

```kotlin
repositories {
  maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/release") }
}
```

Comment: Note that since February 2023 the url changed to: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/